# Matlab Simulink - How do I output an array from my level 2 S Function?

Tags: arrays, matlab, simulink

I have a S function that takes arrays as inputs from an excel file and does computations using the arrays. The ultimate result in the S function block is a Nx1 array. I have tried assigning the Nx1 array to the sFunc.OutputPort(1).Data, but it gives me error saying I am attempting to assign a length N vector to a length 1 vector.

I want to be able to output the array and feed it into another S function in Simulink and to a scope to plot the data against another array (time).

Any help would be greatly appreciated！

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried adding a [`simout`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/slref/toworkspace.html) block to the output of your S function? (I think maybe I am misunderstanding your question).

Answer (score 1):

For a Level-2 M-file s-function, you should explicitly specify the Outport dimensions in the setup() function:

```
function setup(block)
....
block.OutputPort(1).Dimensions       = [N 1];
```

Then you can output your array like this in the Output function:

```
function Output(block)
...
block.OutputPort(1).Data = ones(N,1);
```

I tried this in a dummy L-2 M-S-Fcn and it worked fine...